# Decrypt python source code at runtime

Tags: encryption, python, source-code

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the source code of some python program if the developer encrypted this source. We download a program in which the source is encrypted. But in order to translate python code into bytecode, special libraries must first decipher the encrypted bytes into code that will be understandable to the interpreter. I am interested in whether it is possible to extract this code during decryption. Or get the source code while the interpreter is running? Is it possible to get the decryption key into the source code, and where is this key located? Is it possible to write a program that can look at the work of the interpreter and as a result output the source code of the executable program?

Comment: Just to check, do you mean "encrypted" code or "compiled" code?

Comment: encrypted python code

Comment: If the code is not compiled, then it must be valid Python code. Period. You may be looking at a file that's not, yet, a Python source but it's actually data that will be decoded by a loader and then run as a Python script. Depending on the specific sample there can be multiple ways of recovering the source. Or none. Impossible to say without a [mcve].

Comment: So, how do you know that it's encrypted? Do you know how it was encrypted?

Comment: Perhaps the code is just _obfuscated_?

Comment: As you can see, we are going to need more details.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine that you control can decrypt it, then you can too. A naive way would be to of find the line of code where the code is actually executed and do a `print` before or after. However the libraries may be built with layers of complexity to make this hard. Also, the code may be also obfuscated, meaning that it will be hard for a human to understand requiring hours and hours of patience. ChatGPT may help understanding obfuscated code.